# how can i get data from php to add json data of vue?

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

Friends, I used `v-if` property of vue js. When I use `foreach` with php, I check if value is `true` or `false`. Now, I have to add php data to data of vue js otherwise I get an error.

For example error it says `breaking_bad undefined`.
I want to say, I can't use `{{ ( $value->slug ) ? $value->slug:''}}`
without `value`.

I have to forward data from php to vue js;

Thanks in advance

```
// My laravel foreach code

@foreach( App\Models\AdvertisementCategories::all() as $value )
                                    <div class="row" v-if="{{ $value->slug }}" data-value="{{$value->slug}}">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h5 class="bg-secondary p-3 advertisement" id="{{$value->id}}" style="cursor:pointer">{{$value->title}} :</h5>
                                            <div class="row advertisement_category_features" v-if="{{$value->slug}}" id="{{$value->id}}">
                                                @foreach( $value->features as $value )
                                                <div class="col-3">
                                                    <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--bold kt-checkbox--success">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="advertisement_category_features[]" value="{{$value->id}}"> {{$value->title}}
                                                        <span></span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @endforeach


// My vue js code

var self = this;

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    name: 'Add Advertisement',
    data: {
        advertisement_type: '',number: true,date: true,sales_type: true,meter: true,
        room: true,year_built: true,heating: true,deposit: true,pool_size: true,
        baths: true,garages: true,last_remodel_year: true,floor: true,floor_location: true,
        dues: true,within_the_site: true,is_furnished: true,is_eligible_credit: true,
        swap: true,using_status: true,workspace: true,kitchen_number:true,
        cephe: true,konut:true,bina:true,banyo:true,sosyal:true,manzara:true,ulasim:true,
        mutfak:true,yapi:true,balkon:true,dekorasyon:true,genel:true,
    },
    methods:{
        advertisement_categories: function(advertisement_categories){
            return advertisement_categories;
        },
        advertisement: function(value){
            this.advertisement_type = value;
            if( this.advertisement_type == "arsa" ){
                this.letTrue();
                this.land();
            }else if( this.advertisement_type == "workplace" ) {
                this.letTrue();
                this.workplace(false);
            }else if( this.advertisement_type == "housing" ) {
                this.letTrue();
                this.housing();
            }
        },
});
```

Comment: Please consider explaining again the issue, rephrasing the full question since it's almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to forward data from PHP to Vue you have multiple options. If your Vue JS code is generated inside a Blade view you can directly render the data into the Vue component.

Another option is to define a shared data layer in global scope. For example: `window.myData = {{ json_encode($phpVarWithData) }}`. You would do this inside your view file.

Even another option (especially for small data) is to use HTML data attributes inside your view like you already do. You should read the data attributes inside Vue's livecycle hooks: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Actually, `v-if="{{ $value->slug }}"` looks a bit strange to me. What do you want to archive with this code? The expression evaluates to `true` if `$value->slug` is not empty. But my guess is that this value never is empty so the `v-if` is redundant.